# Deploy Nexus Repository in cluster mode

Tags: cluster-computing, nexus, nexus3

I start my Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3.9.0 as docker container in one node mode. But it has opportunity to start in a cluster.

Can I start free version of Nexus in a cluster mode? If I can, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HA Clustering is a PRO (licensed/paid) feature only as noted in https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/High+Availability+-+Introduction.